# Can anyone justify how the output of the following program?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the result of assigning multi-character char constant to a char variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737320/how-to-determine-the-result-of-assigning-multi-character-char-constant-to-a-char)

I compiled the program given below and the output was `'a'`.
My questions are:

Since the character can only hold one character at a time then how in line 3 it is possible?

How can it give the output `a`?

```
int main()
{
    char ch='ab'; /* line 3 */
    printf("%c",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer you seek: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11737410/1355166

Comment: Because character literals (your `'ab'`) are of type `int`. Your program converted the `int` with value `'ab'` (the value is implementation specific) to a value of type `char` during the initialization; The resulting value (of type `char`) is `'a'`.

Comment: The result of the conversion is also implementation-defined, at least if plain `char` is signed, though it's likely to take the low-order 8 bits of the implementation-defined value of `'ab'`.  (On my system, the program prints `b`, after several compile-time warnings.)

Comment: @pmg: what is the meaning of implementation specific.......and what should have been the output if i would have used char ch='abc'

Comment: @KeithThompson: what is the implementation defind value of 'ab' ?what does it mean ,

Comment: @krishnaChandra It means the standard doesn't prescribe how multi-character constants are interpreted, each implementation can define its own way, but must document which way was chosen.

Comment: "implementation specific" means it can be 96174 in one computer and 34707 in another. The Standard does not mandate a specific way to turn multi-character character literals into a value.

Comment: @KeithThompson: it may be implementation specific but how 2 characters can store in a single character variable

Comment: The output when you use `char ch='abc';` can be different in different computers ... or the same computer with a different compiler ... or the same compiler with different options.

Comment: @pmg: but when i used char ch='abc' then i got a error message that the character constant must  be one or two character long

Comment: @krishnaChandra Are `int`s 16 bits for your compiler? A character constant, be it single character, `'a'` or multi-character, `'ab'` has type `int`. When you assign that `int` to a `char` variable, the value is converted if it isn't representable as a `char`. If `char` is unsigned, the conversion is specified by the standard (reduction modulo `CHAR_MAX + 1`), if it is signed, the conversion is implementation-defined (and may raise an implementation-defined signal).

Comment: There is hardly any good reason to use multi-character constants like `'ab'`. As you've seen, they're not at all portable. Puzzles like this can be useful, but it's generally more useful to ask "How can I do <whatever> in C?" than "What does this bizarre C construct, that should never appear in production code, mean?"