# Not receiving desired output from array in C

Tags: c, arrays, 8051

I have an array:

```
int arr[]={'1','2','4','8','16','32','64','128'};
```

And I'm calling it with this line:

```
a=arr[a];
```

However, I'm not getting the desired output. The input is as expected (I've checked this, it goes from 0-7), but the output comes out as `49,50,52,56,49,51,54,49` depending on the input. What have I done wrong?

EDIT: Quotation marks mean ASCII. Knew I'd missed something simple.

Comment: Is this really on an 8051?!

Comment: Why not use `(1 << a)` instead? (beside obvious array initialization error covered by answers already)

Comment: You array should be `const`. Also, enable (moar!) compiler warnings since `'16'` is a multi-character character literal which are rarely useful and thus tend to generate warnings.

Comment: Yes, this is really an 8051. 

I'm not really sure what (a << 1) does. Can you explain further?

I wasn't supposed to be working with ascii, hence removing the quotation marks gives me what I was after. I was working for an example and forgot what was what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializers in the array are character literals, not `int` values so the array will be populated with the numeric value of each character literal (multibyte character literals, such as `'32'`, are permitted but their value is implementation defined, see [How to determine the result of assigning multi-character char constant to a char variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737320/how-to-determine-the-result-of-assigning-multi-character-char-constant-to-a-char/11737414#11737414)).

To get the desired output use `int` literals:

```
int arr[]={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};
```

Answer (score 2):

The output is correct. 49 is the ASCII value of the character `'1'` which is what you have as the first entry in the array, for example.

Comment: Gah, ascii, knew it was something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this declaration `int arr[]={'1','2','4','8','16','32','64','128'};`, you are storing the ascii values as you are declaring them to be character strings. Hence, the values of `49` for `1`, `50` for `2`,`52` for `4`, `56` for `8`, `49` for `1` of `16`, `51` for `3` of `32`, `54` for `6` of `64` and `49` for `1` of `128`, which is retrieved when you index into the array.

Answer (score 0):

`int arr[]={'1','2','4','8','16','32','64','128'};`
You should declare your `arr` array as `char` instead of `int`.

The exact reason you are getting numbers instead of characters is that the output library you are using is called with an `int` parameter. From that, the library understands the data you are giving it should be interpreted and displayed as numbers.

Also, the numbers you are getting are the **[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)** or number equivalent of the values in your array.