# printf with unmatched format and parameters

Tags: c

i'm trying to understand the printf function.

I know after i read about this function that the c compiler automatically casts all the parameters which are smaller than int like chars and shorts to int.
I also know that long long int (8 bytes) is not casted and pushed to the stack as it is.

so i wrote this simple c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int a = 0x4444444443434343LL; 
    // note that 0x44444444 is 4 times 0x44 which is D in ascii.
    // and 0x43434343 is 4 times 0x43 which is C in ascii.

    printf("%c %c\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

that creates the a variable whose size is 8 bytes and pushes it to the stack.
i also know that the printf loops through the format string and when it sees %c it will increment the pointer by 4 (because it knows that a char was converted to int - example below)

something like: 
char c = (char) va_arg(list, int) -->

(*(int *)((pointer += sizeof(int)) - sizeof(int)))

as you can see it gets the 4 bytes when the pointer points, and increment it by 4

**My question is:**

in my logic, it should print on little endian machines C D
this is not what happens and i ask why? im sure some of you know more than me about the implementation and thats why i ask his question.

EDIT: the actual result is C with some garbage character follows it.

i know some might say that its undefined behavior - it really depends on the implementation and i just want to know the logic of the implementation..

Answer (score 4):

Your logic would have explained the behavior of early C compilers in the 70s and 80s. Newer ABIs use a variety of methods to pass arguments to functions, including variable argument functions. You have to study your system ABI to understand how parameters are passed in your case, inferring from constructions that have explicit undefined behavior does not help.

By the way, types shorter than `int` are not cast or casted, they are **promoted** to `int`. Note that `float` values are converted to `double` when passed to variable argument functions. Non integer types and integer types larger than `int` are passed according to the ABI, which means they may be passed in regular registers or even special registers, not necessarily *on the stack*.

`printf` relies on macros defined in `<stdarg.h>` to hide these implementation details, and thus can be written in a portable manner for architectures with different ABIs and different standard type sizes.

Comment: what is the difference between promoted and casted? each system implements its own <stdarg.h> that fits its calling conventions?

Comment: casting refers to the syntax one can use to force explicit conversion of a value to another type, such as `(double)1`. The C Standard defines a set of rules for small integral types to be promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` in expressions, and another set of rules for values to be converted to a common type in binary expressions such as `1.1 + 1`. These promotions and conversions are implicit. Some coding style guides insist on avoiding such implicit conversion and require explicit casts everywhere at the cost of decreased readability and potential portability issues.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding here, as revealed by the comment

> according to the format string here the compiler should know that 4 bytes were pushed, convert 4 bytes to char and print it...

But the problem is that *there is no rule saying that C uses a single, byte-addressed stack for everything*.

Different processor architectures can -- and do -- use a variety of techniques for passing arguments to functions.  Some arguments may be passed on a conventional stack, but others may be passed in registers, or via other techniques.  Arguments of different types may be passed in different types of registers (32 vs. 64 bit, integer vs. floating point, etc.).

Obviously a C compiler has to know how to properly pass arguments for the platform it's compiling for.  Obviously a variadic function like `printf` has to be carefully written to fetch its variable arguments correctly, based on the platform it's being used on.  But a format specifier like `%d` does not, repeat not, simply mean "pop 4 bytes from the stack and treat them as an `int`".  Similarly, `%c` does *not* mean "pop 4 bytes and print the resulting integer as a character".  When `printf` encounters the format specifier `%c` or `%d`, it needs to arrange to *fetch the next argument of type `int`, whatever it takes to do that*.  And if, in fact, the next argument actually passed by the calling code was *not* of type `int` -- for example if, as here, the next argument was actually of type `long long int` -- there's just no way of knowing in general what might happen.

Specifically, when `printf` has just seen a `%d` or `%c` specifier, what it does internally is the equivalent of calling

```
va_arg(argp, int)
```

And this literally says, "fetch the next argument of type `int`".  And then it's actually up to the author of `va_arg` (and the rest of the functions and macros declared in `<stdarg.h>`) to know exactly what it takes to fetch the next argument of type `int` on this particular platform.

Clearly it is possible to know what will actually happen on a particular platform.  (Obviously the author of `va_arg` had to know!)  But you won't figure it out based on the C language itself, or by making guesses about what you think ought to happen.  You're going to have to read about the ABI -- the Application Binary Interface -- that specifies the details of function calling conventions on your platform.  These details can be hard to find, because very few programmers actually care about them.

I said that "`printf` has to be carefully written to fetch its variable arguments correctly", but actually I misspoke slightly, because as I said later, "it's actually up to the author of `va_arg` to know exactly what it takes".  You're right, it is possible to write a reasonably portable implementation of `printf`.  There's an example in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html).

If you want to know more about function calling conventions, another interesting topic to read about is *Foreign Function Interfaces* or FFI.  (For example, there's another library `libffi` that helps you to -- portably! -- perform some more exotic tasks involved in manipulating function arguments.)

Comment: so the "problem" is that the compiler may decide to pass the parameters in a different way than the stack, and to fully understand what will happen on extreme cases i have to understand my system ABI which specifies the function calling conventions? if C would use a single, byte-addressed stack for everything, and ints were 4 bytes and long long ints were 8 bytes, than my assumption would be correct?  - a lot of ifs i know

Comment: @ליאבלוי If your example had been `long long int a = 0x0000004400000043LL; ` I might agree with you.  (I might.  But yes, that is a lot of ifs!)

Comment: why would it need to be like that? char a = 0x00000044 is exactly like char b = 0x44444444.

Comment: @ליאבלוי Why do you think those are exactly alike?  Who says that when you print an `int` as a `char`, you take the low 8 bits and throw away the rest?  There are ways of manipulating greater-than-8-bit characters, you know.

Comment: but we are talking about ascii chars whose size is 1 byte, also little endian machine that the least significant byte will be stored first, then the casting to a char will take the first byte, in your case and also in mine 0x44 and 0x43, please explain your self, i might talk nonsense

Comment: @ליאבלוי But I am *not* talking about ASCII characters.  I am talking about C characters, which might be more than 8 bits, and might use character sets other than ASCII -- like maybe Unicode.  I can imagine `printf("%c", 0x01B5)` printing Ƶ.  (And then there's the matter of `char c = 'ab';`, but that's a mindbender.)

Comment: @ליאבלוי : are there systems where it works the way you describe ? Sure. Should you rely on that ? No. There are no guarantees it'll still work that way tomorrow, or under otherwise slightly different circumstances.

Comment: @SteveSummit if we are talking about characters whose size is bigger than 1 byte (unicode for example) then i agree, 0x44444444 doesn't equal 0x00000044. what do you mean here "char c = 'ab';" btw

Comment: @SanderDeDycker after the comments here i understood that every system is different, and every compiler may implement things the way he wants - so i cant rely on this of course. i just wanted to know that if all the environment would be set as i took for granted - int is 4 bytes, long long ints are 8 bytes and the way the compiler will pass the parameters is the stack only - will my assumption be correct (also ascii characters apparently)

Comment: @ליאבלוי If it will put your mind at ease I will say this: "Yes, you are right.  It will work exactly the way you suggest, assuming you're using a machine like the one you're thinking of, that works exactly the way you suggest."  (But as you've now discovered, there are real machines which work rather differently.)

Comment: As for `char c = 'ab'`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737320/how-to-determine-the-result-of-assigning-multi-character-char-constant-to-a-char).

Comment: @SteveSummit i could write complete nonsense and your answer will still be valid lol.. thanks for your answer btw

Answer (score 0):

[There are simply too many <strike>notes</strike> types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCud8H7z7vU)

C specifies 11 integer types `signed char`, `char`, … `unsigned long long` as distinct types.  Aside from `char` must match `signed char` or `unsigned char`, these could be implemented as 10 different encodings or just 2 (Use 64-bit signed or unsigned for all).
The standard library has a `printf()` specifiers for each of those 11.  (Due to sub-`int` promotions, there are additional concerns).

So far no real issues.

Yet C has lots of *other types* with `printf()` specifiers:

```
ju           uintmax_t
jd           intmax_t
zu           size_t
td           ptrdiff_t
PRIdLEASTN   int_leastN_t  where N is 8, 16, 32, 64
PRIuLEASTN   uint_leastN_t
PRIdN        intN_
PRIuN        uintN_t
Many others
```

In *general*<sup>1</sup> these additional types, could be **distinct** from **or compatible** with the 11 above.

Any time code uses these *other types* in a `printf()`, the distinct/compatible issue will arise and prevent many compilers from detecting/providing the best suggested matching print specifier.

<sup>1</sup> Various conditions/limitations exist.