# C arguments from the C primer plus 6e should effect print

Tags: c

C written in Emacs

```
// print1.c --displays some properties of printf()
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int ten = 10;
  int two = 2;

  printf("Doing it right: ");
  printf("%d minus %d is %d\n", ten, 2, ten - two);
  printf("Doing it wrong: ");
  printf("%d minus %d is %d\n", ten); // forgot 2 arguments

  return 0;
}
```

> ```
> Welcome to the Emacs shell
> ```

Output:

```
~ $ ./a.exe
Doing it right: 10 minus 2 is 8

Doing it wrong: 10 minus 2 is 8
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relies on external links, and those can break.

Comment: The arguments of printf doesn't match the format string, therefore the behaviour of your program is undefined. Google "C undefined behaviour"

Comment: Thanks for the edit, close vote retracted.

Comment: [printf with unmatched format and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51058371/995714)

Comment: It apparently works probably because the 4th invocation of `printf()` finds on the stack the values that were put there on its 2nd invocation. Remove the 2nd invocation of `printf()` and the last one will print garbage.

Comment: This online C interpreter can tell you that the last `printf` call is undefined: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/61b3753e

Answer (score 1):

It should do nothing of the sort.

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

One manifestation of undefined behaviour is the compiler figuring out what you really wanted to do. Don't ever rely on that though.

Comment: Why the answer is right, because of Eshell?

Comment: It's because of something. Don't dwell on it too much. Check the generated assembly if you're really curious.

Comment: get, thanks, just check code carefully for the rookie!